# ASN1C DER decoder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, asn.1, der

I'm trying to create simple DER decoder - console application that just outputs content of given data structure (encoded in DER format, like **[this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#Example_encoded_in_DER)**).

I have problems with running this example: **[A ''Rectangle'' Decoder](http://lionet.info/asn1c/asn1c-usage.html#SECTION02320000000000000000)** .

I'm trying to compile it with MSVC and I have problems with `#include <inttypes.h>` and `#include <netinet/in.h>`. Also type `ssize_t` is undefined.

Here's what I've done for now:
1. At [Online ASN.1 Compiler](http://lionet.info/asn1c/asn1c.cgi) I pasted this code into textfield:

```
RectangleModule1 DEFINITIONS ::=
BEGIN

Rectangle ::= SEQUENCE {
    height  INTEGER,
    width   INTEGER
}

END
```

2. I selected ***"Use native machine types"*** and ***"Generate PER support"*** options.
3. It ***"Compiled OK"*** so I downloaded that output **.tgz**
4. Created empty project int Visual Studio 2010, drag-n-dropped source files extracted from this **.tgz**
5. Set additional include directory to "skeletons" directory of ASN1C
6. Tried to build it.

What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have used ASN1C successfully in the past.  Perhaps it would be best to concentrate on getting that working before looking for alternatives?

Comment: Try looking at yaz-asncomp and ODR module of yaz project www.indexdata.com

Comment: @trojanfoe: You were successfully using ASN1C on **Linux** by using **GCC** I guess...

Comment: @LihO Yes that's right.  I assumed it would work just as well under MSVC.

Comment: @trojanfoe: After few corrections I got it work under MSVC too ;) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that code generated by ASN1C must be modified in order to compile it with MSVC and to use it in Windows environment.

1. `#include <inttypes.h>` should be replaced with `#define ssize_t SSIZE_T`
2. `#include <netinet/in.h>` should be replaced with `#include <Winsock2.h>`
3. keyword `inline` should be removed from `static` functions defined in `asn_internal.h`

After that, everything works fine ;)

Comment: In VS2005 it woked for me without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a correct ASN defintion file. Then go to link 
    http://lionet.info/asn1c/asn1c.cgi

paste your ASN definition in the given window. Press the button "Proceed with ASN.1 compilation". If you get any compilation error rectify those. After the compilation is successful it will generate the code for your decoder. Give it a try its good.